# Bluetooth 0930:021c not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: bluetooth

Ubuntu detects the bluetooth hardware (it shows the bluetooth icon in the status bar), and I can turn it on or off and set the visibility and such. However, it is never able to find any bluetooth device.

lsusb shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0930:021c Toshiba Corp.
```

uname -a shows:

```
Linux lucas-Leon 4.0.2-040002-generic #201505081529 SMP Fri May 8 15:30:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have tried another kernel (4.0.2) but it doesn't work either.

I also tried:

```
echo 0930 021c > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id
```

"usb-devices | awk '/021c/' RS=" output:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0930 ProdID=021c Rev=00.01
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

"lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6611]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/021c/' RS=` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` reminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

This adapter `[0930:021c]` is not supported by Linux kernel yet.

The [Bug Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1502781)

I fixed it and added to ppa. The module can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/bluetooth
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install btusb-lp1502781-dkms
```

The bluetooth adapter should work after reboot.

The modules built are for Ubuntu 14.04.3 with kernel 3.19, Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Please do not forget to ping me like this @PL.Lucas

Comment: I have reported the bug. Finally, I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 beta. Then I can help in new Ubuntu release. The bug link is:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1502781

Comment: This is the bug link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1502781

Comment: @PL.Lucas I updated the answer.